# Querying encrypted data in SQLite

Tags: qt, encryption, sqlite, hashmap

I want to query encrypted data from my SQLite database.

For each row, I'm using XOR operation on every value, convert it toBase64 and then INSERT it in the database.

Now I need to find a way to SELECT the encrypted values.

i.e:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name_column BETWEEN 'value1' AND 'value2'
```

Considering the huge information in my database, how can I do that without having to decrypt all the table to get the wanted rows?

Comment: You could show the code with the save data in the database.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible. You are using `BETWEEN 'value1' AND 'value2'`. The database can only see the XORed strings and `BETWEEN` will not work as expected. Even if you find a way to decrypt the strings on-the-fly with SQLITE (remember XOR calling again will decrypt) it's not very efficient and resource consuming when there are thousand of entries.

So in order to continue with your problem you could have a look at [this](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki) extension list. SQLITE seems to provide some *very basic* encryption modules, which can XOR the **whole database** with a key you defined. (not recommended)

> This file describes the SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE) for SQLite.
>   The SEE allows SQLite to read and write encrypted database files. All
>   database content, including the metadata, is encrypted so that to an
>   outside observer the database appears to be white noise.
>
> This file contains the complete source code to the SEE variant that
>   does weak XOR encryption. Do not take this file seriously. It is for
>   demonstration purposes only. XOR encryption is so weak that it hardly
>   qualifies as "encryption".

The way you want to do it won't work, unless you read all values of a column to your Qt program, decrypt them and check if VALUE X is BETWEEN A and B.